# Possible to auto allow active x on local site?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, local

I've got an html file on my desktop that runs some javascript and activex within IE, so naturally when it opens it prompts to allow activex. My question is, is there anyway to auto allow activex for this specific local site/file? Allowing all ActiveX from all sites is obviously a security issue, so I'm attempting to see if I can allow for JUST this local site.

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL to intranet zone and modify the settings for intranet zone only

Hope this helps.